# "Media Library" shows as empty, despite images being present

Tags: images, uploads, media-library, migration, clone-site

I am trying to clone a WordPress site, but the files in `wp-content/uploads` aren't shown in the the Media Library:

- **OK:** I have created a new subdomain for a new installation of WordPress, and I have exported all WP posts and WP pages from the old site, and imported into the new. On the filesystem I have also copied the entire /wp-content/uploads/ directory, and given all those files the proper permissions and owner/group to match the new server.
- **OK:** images that are linked from within pages appear as they should. So I know the images "work."
- **Problem:** The "Media Library" at `/wp-admin/upload.php` is empty, as if the images weren't there. But I've proven that they are.

--> What can cause this? How can I fix this?

Comment: It sounded like the images were not imported as *attachments*? Items in the media library are attachments, which means they have their own post where the type is `attachment`, and an attached file. Each post also have a metadata like the width and height of the attached file. Without those, copying the files will not make them appear in the media library. So, maybe you can try re-importing the posts and pages.. And if you use the [default importer](https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/wordpress/import/#wordpress), it can import the images *as attachments*.

Comment: the media library does not display files, it displays posts of type `attachment`, the contents of the uploads folder are irrelevant until you try to load them with the browser

Comment: **Sally is correct: there were just files on disk, no attachments in WordPress.** This is because I exported all *posts* and *pages* but deliberately not *attachments* due to total file size; I merely copied the actual files. Thank you!